How to set the font in ApachePDF Box version 3.0.2
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.state.RenderingMode;
import java.io.*;


  PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
  PDPage page1 = new PDPage();
  document.addPage(page1);
  PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page1);
  stream.beginText();
  stream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
  stream.newLineAtOffset(50, 500);

  stream.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.FILL_STROKE);

Why is TIMES_ROMAN not resolved?
I have tried changing the version I have to before the migration so that I can
follow online tutorials, but that errors and is unable to compile.
I have fiddled with imports, no change.

If you had read the PDFBox 3 migration guide, you would have seen this item.

You can set the font in the following way:
stream.setFont(new PDType1Font(FontName.TIMES_ROMAN), 12);

The constructor for PDType1Font is defined as follows in https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/latest/index.html:
PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName baseFont)

